# Using the definite article with comparatives and superlatives, for example "the sooner the better"

Tags: articles, definite-article

I would like to know the meaning of structures concerning the definite article "the"-"the"+comparative or superlative adjective(adverb) structures- to be more specific, these ones: the more...the better; the most... the best.

Examples:

- the more...the better: *the sooner the better*.
- the most...the best:  We like *this book the best*.

If you can provide some information of this structure I would be grateful.

Comment: The structure, such as it is, works with positives as well as comparatives and superlatives.  That is to say, "the good", "the better" and "the best" all make sense.  Offhand, I can't think of any [substantive adjective](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-substantive-adjective.htm) that doesn't require the definite article "the".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comparatives and superlatives ("better", "soonest") are *adjectives* that would not normally take the definite article "the".  However, it is grammatical to use the adjective as a noun, where the adjective stands as an *ellipsis* of a noun phrase.  For example:

> Which of these shirts do you want?
>   I'll take the *blue* (shirt).
>
> How many are in your group?
>   We are *three* (people).
>
> When forced to choose between evils, try to pick the *lesser* (evil).
>
> Among the runners, she is the *best* (of all the runners).

As in your example, the adjective can also stand for an adverbial phrase that would otherwise include a noun:

> We like this book the *best* (of all the books).

There are also set idiomatic phrases like "the X the better", but again these are elliptical phrases that omit redundant information.

> When should I arrive?
>   The *sooner* (moment in time that you can arrive), (it will be) the *better* (situation).

I don't think there is any special rule around the use of this other than the sentence should still make sense with the noun omitted.  For example:

> When ordering wine at a restaurant you should always pick the *least*.

The least what?  It's not clear from context if I mean "the least expensive wine" or "the least fruity wine" or something else.  Of course people say things like this all the time, which can require the listener to ask follow-up questions.

There are other cases where the definite article can be used before a comparative or superlative adjective, for example if the adjective has been converted into an ordinary or proper noun, as in someone's name or title.  For example, the boxer Muhammad Ali was nicknamed "The Greatest".

[More information.](http://www.brighthubeducation.com/english-homework-help/40011-the-use-of-adjectives-as-nouns/)

Answer (score 0):

When comparatives are used in the selective sense, the definite article 'the' is used.
EX:

> Padma is clever of the two sisters.(incorrect)
>
> Padma is the cleverest of the two sisters.(correct)